# How can I stretch a shirt?

Tags: clothing

I currently have a t-shirt that only barely fits. I know that if I were to put it in the dryer after I wash it, it will shrink, so I've been taking it out after the wash and air-drying it. This is annoying to do and I would like to avoid it.

**How can I stretch out this shirt** so I can just wash it normally (washer & dryer) like the rest of my clothes?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkqd6.jpg) is a comparison between what it looks like before and after being put in the dryer. (Not my photo, but it's the same shirt I have.) Unfortunately, I can't just buy a bigger one because the shirt was only sold in one size.

Comment: well that's exactly why different sizes exist. It would probably be better to "shrink" yourself than stretch the t-shirt out :-)

Comment: @LaurentS.: Like I said in the question, I would've bought a bigger one but they only sold it in one size.

Comment: On a lighter note : By going to Gym ;)

Comment: @MohitKanwar - the problem is I'm too tall, not too fat :)

Comment: Ha Ha! It would work for me that's why shared. If Only !!

Comment: Please mention the fabric type, it will help.

Comment: @sankoobaba: The tag's in japanese, so I'm not sure, but google translate says one symbol looks like "cotton" with a 92% next to it, and the other is this word with 6 characters with 8% next to it.

Comment: How bout like you wear the shirt and blow dry yourself on heat setting. Could that work? Idk im also here looking for answers.

Answer (score 1):

Take it to a Laundromat - they have stretching services!

Answer (score 0):

You could try soaking the shirt in a salt brine. Just fill a container with water, add salt until the water is cloudy, put the shirt in the water and let it sit for 3 or 4 days.

This "ages" the shirt. I've done it several times, and my shirts come out nice and soft.

I'm not sure whether or not it will stop your shirt from shrinking, but it does affect the fabric in such a way that it becomes softer, so it might also stop it from shrinking.

You could try testing on a white tshirt or something first.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'd do:
I expect the fibres will loosen when in wet and warm environment (but not hot, only warm, like not above 40 degrees Celsius) and then when the drying part comes - stretch it over something, like a canvas, all the way to it's limits, and then let dry naturally or dry with cold air. (not with the heating option of a fan...)

my theory lies in the fact that stuff tends to re-shape and occupy more volume when in warm environment (picture ice melting...) and when in cold environment stuff tends to shrink or at least just stay put. 
I think it would work with fiber if you stretch it before it cools off from the washing machine.
In fact, remember how clothes stretch a bit when you iron it (heat it up). Maybe it would work after ironing it and then stretching it and letting it cool up like that too.